# Difference between responding to "danke" with "bitte" versus "gerne"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, usage

I hear native German speakers respond to a *danke* with *bitte* as often as with *gerne*.

Is there a semantic difference between the two of them? Or a usage rule behind the choice? Is one more polite than the other?

Comment: I don't think that I really see any significant difference in using one over the other, but mgoni made a point. If I made something rather unwillingly, I'd never say "gerne" as I wasn't happy to do the favor; but I still might say "bitte". If I did the favor willingly (or happily), I'd go with both equally often — I  guess.

Comment: @Em1 It is better to note that if something done unwillingly, it can be also said that: **ungern**

Comment: "Gerne" as an answer to "danke" is a newer phenomenon in spoken German. I would consider it as a colloquial sloppiness, and my native feel for language always gets a little bit offended when I hear it. ;-)

Comment: Note that there are plenty of other (maybe regional) variants of how to answer *danke*, such as (mentioned in comments below) "nichts zu danken", "keine Ursache", "für nichts", "kein Problem", etc.

Comment: Aventurin is right. I can't prove it, but in my opinion "gerne" is  the outcome of modern marketing strategies intending to train employees to become more customer-friendly. In fact, very often people working at service hotlines close conversation by a "gerne" with a certain intonation and (fake?) enthusiasm. Also have a look at my answer to https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56404/34192 .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"*Bitte*" is the "standard" answer to "*Danke*".

"*Gerne*" is short for "*Gern geschehen!*".
 According to the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gern), "*gern*" means

> mit freudiger Bereitwilligkeit, Vergnügen

It therefore implies that the speaker was happy to help or do a favor ... and it all sounds more polite.

Answer (score 10):

With a quick search I found this (it's a bit tongue in cheek, but he's quite well known as a linguist):
http://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/fragen-an-den-zwiebelfisch/bitte-danke-bitte

The author argues that "*Bitte*" is short for "*Ich bitte Sie, das war doch selbstverständlich!*" or similar sentences (maybe "*Oh please, that was nothing!*" in English). Here, you do not accept the gratitude, in your view you did nothing that would require it.

Answering with "*Gerne*" is noted as a new trend, mainly because people didn't understand the first option anymore. There you accept the gratitude, but express that you liked to do the action, so it was no problem for you.

So in conclusion, "*Bitte*" may be a bit more old-fashioned, but also more polite in theory.

Comment: I would follow @mgoni's answer and say that "gerne" is more polite because it additionally implies that the helping person didn't do it unwillingly. It leaves the helped person with a better feeling i guess.

Comment: @trixn Arguably with "bitte" you do it so willingly that you don't even need a thanks. However, in current usage I would agree that "gerne" could be considered to be more polite because people actually understand what it means. The historical usage just says that "bitte" is comparable to, for example, "nichts zu danken".

Answer (score 5):

"Bitte" corresponds to the English "You're welcome."

"Gerne" is more like "My pleasure."

The implication of the first set is, "Ok. here's what's yours."

The implication of the second set is, the doer feels that the *asker* is doing a favor, something "A to A" on Ouora.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with the sets and favors.

Comment: @problemofficer: "Sets" refer to sentences. Set 1 is "bitte" and "you're welcome." Set 2 is "gerne" and "my pleasure." The implication of the second set is that the asker is asking the second person to do something they would want to do anyway. Example: First person, "Would you like have sex?" Second person, "Gerne," or "my pleasure."

Comment: Hm, but this contradicts the answer imo. In general I think it is still confusing. Maybe you want to do a rewrite.

Comment: @problemofficer: I wrote, "the doer [recipient] of the [sexual] request feels that the asker [of the sex] is doing the favor," (not the "requestee"). Recipients of "Ask to answer" on Quora often feel that way when asked to expound of their favorite topic, even though they are technically the provider (requestee) of the favor. I'll agree that the fundamental concept is confusing, because it is "reverse" psychology..

Answer (score 3):

For most people, *bitte* and *gerne* are almost entirely exchangeable when they are used as a response to *danke.* If anything, I would perceive *gerne* as slightly more polite/formal and therefore would tend to use it less with family or close friends. But that’s more of a very vage tendency.

Comment: Diese Antwort entspricht genau dem, was ich auch empfinde. *Gerne* wird nur seltener verwendet, steht deswegen etwas heraus, ist aber ansonsten völlig gleich in der Bedeutung.